# How to make work a project cloned with git in another PC with Kendo Asp Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

we are two people working in the same project.

In my pc works fine without any error, but after my colleague cloned the project (made with C# ASP MVC) he gets this error

[image]

He has installed teleriks/Kendos on his machine, so we can't figure it out what's happening.

Could you please help us to made this work?

Comment: Most likely that if you yourself clone the same project into another location it will not work in exactly the same manner it does not work for your colleague. When sharing code you need to make sure that (1) everything is shared what is needed, (2) the build scripts are self-sufficient to build the project from scratch and (3) for any manual steps you have a README included.

Comment: @Oleg We double checked pre requisites, everything is installed

Comment: Then I can only go back to my original comment: your git repository does not contain all the code, scripts and config files needed for the build, your build scripts are not complete or you have some manual steps to go through which are not documented anywhere. In 99% of all situations there is no magic in building something upon checkout, it is just following those 3 rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing a reference to the Kendo.Mvc.dll in the web.config of the solution. The reason that it works in your dev pc could be that you have that reference binding in a web.config file in some container folder  higher up in the hierarchy.

For more information see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx